# Are there any good opensource projects based on Rails3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to develop a digg-like website and decide to use Rails3. I am new with Rails3, so i want to get some opensource project as a reference

Comment: This was a good question in its time, so I feel compelled to explain my "close" vote.  This question fit the site guidelines when it was asked, but those guidelines have since changed to preclude recommendations for resources.  The current standard is intended to apply to all questions, no matter when they were asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help: http://www.opensourcerails.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are a lot. Of the top of my head:

- http://refinerycms.com/
- https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora

Also not many projects have rails 3 branches being developed:

- https://github.com/michaeldv/fat_free_crm/tree/rails3
- https://github.com/radiant/radiant/tree/rails3

Hope that helps